# Mongoose 'populate' not populating

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-populate

I am building a fairly simple application on the MEAN stack and I am really out of my depth, especially when it comes to mongoose. I have found the mongoose documentation very difficult to wrap my head around and cannot find answers anywhere else.

My issue is this: I have a bunch of users, these users have repositories and the repositories have repository providers (GitHub, BitBucket etc).

A user has many repositories and a repository has one repository type.

My user file contains the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema   = mongoose.Schema; 

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    repositories: [{
        name: String,
        branches: [{
            name: String,
            head: Boolean,
            commits: [{
                hash: String,
                date: Date,
                message: String,
                contributer: String,
                avatar: String
            }]
        }],
        repoType: { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'RepoProviders'
        }
    }]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

// This is where the magic doesn't happen :(

User.find({ name: "John Smith"}).populate({path: 'repoType'}).exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(user);
});
```

RepoProvider.js contains:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RepoProviderSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var RepoProvider = mongoose.model('RepoProviders', RepoProviderSchema);
module.exports = RepoProvider;
```

I am creating user documents in mongo and manually assigning a repoType id hash (taken from an existing repoType document).

When I console.log the User, the repo type is set to the id but there is no relationship returned:

```
[ { _id: 5547433d322e0296a3c53a16,
    email: 'john@smith.com',
    name: 'John Smith',
    __v: 0,
    repositories: 
     [ { name: 'RepoOne',
         repoType: 5547220cdd7eeb928659f3b8,
         _id: 5547433d322e0296a3c53a17,
         branches: [Object] } ] } ]
```

How do I properly set and query this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to `repoType` in the [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) method:

```
User.find({ name: "John Smith"}).populate({path: 'repositories.repoType'}).exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: Oh man... do you know how long I have spent on this?! And it comes down to that! Ugggh... I was ready to run screaming back to PHP. Thanks some much for your help!

Comment: :D Mongoose can be a bit confusing with the sparse documentation but the project was transitioned recently and the new maintainers are working hard at resolving that (among a lot of other things).

Comment: Ah good news! It would really help to have a simple 'getting started guide' with complete examples, none of this fill in the blanks nonsense that is going on at the moment in their documentation.