# When I use mongoose's populate(), the desired field in collection is not showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose's populate(), but the result omits the field. I cant's find the populated field with some value. Every other field in collection which is not using "ref" is showing in collection.

I have tried finding solution in [Missing field in Mongo/Mongoose Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623005/missing-field-in-mongo-mongoose-query-results), [Mongoose 'populate' not populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027477/mongoose-populate-not-populating) and several other solutions, but it doesn't work for me.

## The model for Room is (*in Line 4, I declared ownerId*) :

```
1 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
2 const roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
3    //_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
4    ownerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
5    memberIds: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' 
6     }],
7    room_name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, 
8    default: ""},
9    password: { type: String, required: true, default: ""},
10    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
11    });
12 module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema, 'Room');
```

## The model for User is :

```
1 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
2 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
3  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
4  email: {
5    type: String,
6    required: true,
7    unique: true,
8    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=? 
9    ^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?: 
10    [a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
11    },
12  user_name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
13  display_name: { type: String, require: false,default: ""},
14  password: { type: String, required: true },
15  user_image: { type: String, required: false, default: 
16  "userAvatar/profile.png"},
17  user_coins: { type: Number, default: 0 },
18  user_aboutme: { type: String, default: "" },
19  user_gender: { type: String, default: ""},
20  user_isVIP: { type: Boolean, default: false },
21  user_isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
22  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
23  user_isOnline: { type: Boolean, default: false }
24  });
25  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'User');
```

## Here, in this code for creating room, in *line 22, I used populate* :

```
1 const Room = require("../models/room");
2 const User = require("../models/user");
3 exports.room_create = (req, res, next) => {
4   User.find({ email: req.body.email })
5    .exec()
6    .then(user => {
7      console.log(user);
8      if (user.length < 1) {
9        return res.status(409).json({
10        message: "User doesn't exists"
11        });
12      } else {
13          const room = new Room({  
14            room_name: req.body.roomname,
15            password: " "
16          });
17          room
18            .save()
19            .then(result => {
20               console.log("The result is: # " +result);
21               Room.find({ room_name: req.body.roomname })
22                .populate('ownerId')
23                .exec()
24                .then(room => {
25                   console.log("I am here ### Here ###");
26                 })
27               res.status(201).json({
28                 message: "Room created"
29               }); 
30             })
31            .catch(err => {
32               console.log(err);
33               res.status(500).json({
34               error: err
35             });
36         });
37       }
38   });
39 };
```

## This is how it connects to mongo in app.js.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/peopleTalk', {
  //peopleTalk contain collections : ["User", "Room"]
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Now, when I send the request, to the server I get status code 201 and there is no error.

But when I check the Room collection, I get **ownerId missing.**

```
> db.Room.find().pretty();
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5c51eaa8bf999c0f339dad04"),
     "memberIds" : [ ],
     "room_name" : "my room",
     "password" : " ",
     "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-01-30T18:19:20.556Z"),
     "__v" : 0
}
```

I expect the output like :

```
> db.Room.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c51eaa8bf999c0f339dad04"),
    "ownerId" : (_here with some value_),
    "memberIds" : [ ],
    "room_name" : "my room",
    "password" : " ",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-01-30T18:19:20.556Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I am using node v11.7.0, mongo v3.6.3, and mongoose ^5.4.0
Please help me out with this, it would be of great help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever explicitly set your ownerId field when you create your room, and it has no default. Thus, the ownerId is not stored in the database because the value is undefined...

Your room creation should look like this:

```
const room = new Room({  
  room_name: req.body.roomname,
  ownerId: user._id,
  password: " "
});
```

Comment: I implemented the solution, and I get the desired field, but the value of ownerId is null now.

Comment: Can you check your database? What is the ownerId value stored there?

Comment: Now I got it, ownerId got the correct value when I explicitly set the ownerId field as ownerId = user[0]._id. Thank u so much for the solution... :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!